# Funcion para comprobar si se estan escribiendo caracateres prohibidos

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Buenas a ver si me pueden ayudar necesito una función que al escribir caracteres en un input = text compruebe si se están escribiendo caracteres prohibidos que están en una constante, aparte de no escribirlos, me tendría que devolver un true o false depende de si se esta o no escribiendo esos caracteres.

```
const forbiddenChars = '_`#*¿?=.,;-±ªº®%/$@~{}()[]<>/\\"|';
```

actualmente tengo esto que me elimina los caracteres prohibidos pero no logro hacer la comprobación si me pueden ayudar.

```
removeForbidden (searchString) {
    const forbiddenChars = '_`#*¿?=.,;-±ªº®%/$@~{}()[]<>/\\"|';
    let myval = searchString;
    for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenChars.length; i++) {
        myval = myval.replace(forbiddenChars[i], '');
    };
    return myval;
}
```

Comment: Usa el método includes() de javascript y devuelve verdadero o falso en función de lo que devuelva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo el método que ya tienes puedes modificarlo un poco para que verifique si está el carácter especial. De ser así retornar un `false`

para eso usa la función [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function verifyForbidden (searchString) {
  const forbiddenChars = '_`#*¿?=.,;-±ªº®%/$@~{}()[]<>/\\"|';
  for (let i = 0; i < forbiddenChars.length; i++) {
      if(searchString.includes(forbiddenChars[i])){
        return false;
       }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(`Hola is ${verifyForbidden('Hola')}`)
console.log(`Hol@ is ${verifyForbidden('Hol@')}`)
console.log(`<Hola> is ${verifyForbidden('<Hola>')}`)
```

También puedes usar expresiones regulares para ver si contiene alguno de esos caracteres

```js
function verifyForbidden (searchString) {
  const regex = /[_`#*¿?=.,;\-±ªº®%\/$@~{}()\[\]<>/\\"|]/;
  return searchString.match(regex) === null
}

console.log(`Hola is ${verifyForbidden('Hola')}`)
console.log(`Hol@ is ${verifyForbidden('Hol@')}`)
console.log(`<Hola> is ${verifyForbidden('<Hola>')}`)
```

Comment: Gracias el método includes() me soluciono.